# newしたインスタンスに含まれるAutowiredを解決したい

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

SpringのAutowiredで困っているのでご教示ください。
HogeClassはmainメソッドでnewを利用してインスタンス生成されます。この仕組みは変更できません。
HogeClassではAutowiredを利用してサービスなどをDIしたいのですが、可能なのでしょうか。

main

```
static void main(String...args) {
    HogeClass hoge = new HogeClass();
    hoge.execute()
}
```

HogeClass

```
@Component
public class HogeClass {
    @Autowired
    HogeService hogeService;

    public void execute() {
        hogeService.hogeMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HogeClass を修正できるのであれば、HogeClass 内で ApplicationContext を作成し、その中で DI 済みのオブジェクトを作ってはどうでしょうか。例えば次のような形です。

```
public class HogeClass {
    public void execute() {
        try (ApplicatoinContext ctx = ...) {
            HogeComponent hoge = ctx.getBean(HogeComponent.class);
            hoge.execute();
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class HogeComponent {
    @Autowired
    HogeService hogeService;

    public void execute() {
        hogeService.hogeMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Component` の代わりに `@Configurable` を使ってみてはどうでしょうか。Configurable は new でも DI 管理下になると思います。

Comment: Configurableに変更しましたが、DIされないようです。特に依存するライブラリなどなくDIできた実績があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

SpringContextにオブジェクトを管理してもらわないと、DIが使えないはずですが。
このサイトで掲載した方法で変更できないでしょうか。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tomotaro1065/20120505/1336191887

要はMainメソッドに以下のように変更

```
ApplicationContext appContext = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:./META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
HogeClass main = appContext.getBean(HogeClass.class);
```

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。しかし、質問文に記載した通り、mainメソッドは変更できません（「この仕組みは変更できません。」）。HogeClass内で代替のことができればよいのですが...